# Publications for small time research

Tags: publications, publishers

I've been working on an interesting sorting algorithm that is efficient for an array of problems. I wrote up a paper on my findings and it has turned into about 5 pages.  I've researched pretty thoroughly and there aren't any papers that use the method I have found or solve the problem I was working on as efficiently.  I'm curious if there is an easy place to publish work.  I got my undergrad in statistics and never did research so I don't really know how the process works.  Just checking to see if y'all have any recommendations.

Comment: I would advice you to prepare your report for conferences such as FOCS, SODA. These are top conferences in the field. Just read a few previously published paper from the same conferences. However, you may talk to one of your professors who might show some interests in the findings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it is at least somewhat common to find a collaborator with more publishing experience, who can help with the process. i would encourage that because personal conversations are a much higher bandwidth connection than Q&A on this site.

if you are intent on getting your work out there alone, you'll choose to target some point on the spectrum from likely rejection at a high-impact journal to certain acceptance at an unimportant conference. a journal that has already published related work is a good option. read their web site, look at their document norms and submission process for an idea what would be involved in getting a yes or no answer. (if it's a no, of course, you get to start over, somewhat wiser.)